# I can't exit the file opened after executing the git command git pull --allow-unrelated-histories

Tags: git, editor, ubuntu-18.04

I was trying to push a project in Git. Using the command `git pull --allow-unrelated-histories`. It opens a file. I can't exit this file. How to get out of this?

[image]

Comment: If not, please add more details.

Comment: Which editor or other program has been opened for this file? Maybe you could show a screenshot?

Comment: What did you do to solve the issue? (You can post an answer)

Comment: @develop_code Please don't add "SOLVED" or similar metadata to post titles. See [Why can't I mark my title as [Solved]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311829/1324). The correct way to mark a question as "solved": accept the answer that solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Change the default git editor to vim from the git directory using the command:

```
git config [--global] core.editor "vim"
```

In my case I did not need [--global]. So I just ran:

```
git config core.editor "vim"
```

After that running the following command opened a vim file:

```
git pull --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Then quit a vim file using :q

Comment: And how did you exit the editor you were in?

Comment: ctrl+z and exited the process: